# background color of table cells using css and html

Tags: html, css

I've coded a table I want it to be like this : even and odd rows have different colors and first row and column have the same color ;
I used colgroup for coloring first column but it doesn't work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        tr.odd{background-color:#f9f;}
        tr.even{background-color:#fcf;}
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <table width="200" border="1">
        <colgroup span="1" style="background:purple;"></colgroup>

        <tr style="background:purple;">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the first column and first row to be headers for the table? If so, you can/should use <th>content</th> instead. You'll also easily be able to style this separately to the rest of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you wanted.

**CSS**

```
table tr td:first-of-type {background-color: purple !important;}
```

```css
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
tr.odd{background-color:#f9f;}
tr.even{background-color:#fcf;}
table tr td:first-of-type {background-color: purple !important;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
<colgroup span="1" style="background:purple;"></colgroup>

  <tr style="background:purple;">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the even and odd rules of the nth-child pseudoclass

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #FCF}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #F9F}
```

Followed by:

```
td:first-of-type,
tr:first-of-type {background: purple}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `nth-child` (IE9+), which also removes the need for even and odd classes in the HTML.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            td {background-color:#f9f;}
            tr:nth-child(even) > td {background-color:#fcf;}
            tr > td:first-child {background-color:purple;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table width="200" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>

    </html>
```